# How to create a plot in matplotlib not of index(x) and df colomn(y) but with colom1 (x) from df and colom2(y) df?)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, indexing

I have a dataframe which i want to plot and assign different colors.
I create a solution that works when i plot `my value = df.age_gps_data` according to index.
But when i try to plot it according to other dataframe value like `df. river_km(x)` and `df.age_gps_data(y)` i have an error

```
"None of [Float64Index([555..009, 555.012 ...]) are in the [index]"
```

This is my solution for plotting:

```
for color1, start, end in gen_repeating(df['color']):
print(start, end)
if start > 0: # make sure lines connect
   start -= 1
idx = df.index[start:end+1]
x = idx
y = df.loc[idx, 'age_gps_data'].tolist()

ax[0].plot(x, y, color=color1)
ax[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))
plt.setp(ax[0].get_xticklabels(),rotation=45)
```

When I change `df.index` to a `df.river_km` I have an error.

This is example of my dataframe:

[image]

How can I aply this solution to plot `df.age_gps_data` to `df.river_km`?
Actualy I were trying set `df.river_km` as index but i have error because it is float number.

Comment: either `df.plot(x='colom1', y='colom2', ax=ax[0])` or `ax[0].plot(x=df['colom1'], y=df['colom2'])`

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks, it plots. But the colors don't set in the right way. I use following `df.plot(x='river_km', y='age_gps_data', color=color1, ax=ax[0])`